# jQuery Plugin - Keep options object separate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I created a jQuery plugin that was working great until I started testing it with more than one object on a page. The problem is that the options object passed to each new plugin object is not always the same one associated with that specific object when I access it from inside a function in the plugin. I have a feeling that I am missing something very simple, so the code might make things more clear.

Method used to create the plugin

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.myPlugin.defaults, options);
        new $.myPlugin($(this), opts);
    });
}
```

Function that accesses the options object

```
$.myPlugin = function($textbox, options) {
    function doSomething($textbox) {
        alert(options.someProperty);
    }
}
```

No matter what options.someProperty was when I created the plugin. The call to doSomething inside the plugin will always return the someProperty of the first options object in the first plugin object I created for example:

```
$textbox.focus(function() { doSomething($textbox); } );
```

This will always return the same someProperty even if different objects with different options objects are focused.

I hope I have made this clear enough. Let me know if you need anymore details.

Comment: What exactly is someproperty?  Is it nested (eg, `options.mouseSettings.clickSpeed`)?

Comment: Nope, just a simple value. var options = { someProperty : true }

Comment: Are you calling dosomething outside the myPlugin method?

Answer (score 1):

You're giving the plugin a reference to the same `options` object for all of the elements.

Try the following:

```
return this.each(function() {
    new $.myPlugin($(this), $.extend({ }, options));
});
```

This will copy the members of the `options` object to a new object each time.  If your `options` object has other objects nested within it, you might need a deep copy, like this: `$.extend(true, { }, options)`

**EDIT**: You need to extend the `options` object inside the `each` method.  Otherwise, you'll still have the same object for all of the elements.

Comment: I was already extending the options object. Sorry I didn't include that in the code sample. Thanks for the quick response though.

Comment: I moved the extend call inside the each loop and still no luck. Anymore ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
function doSomething($textbox) {
```

to

```
var doSomething = function($textbox) {
```

to ensure that you are creating separate doSomething methods that use separate [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).  (the first version will create a single function the first time it's called, and reuse that function and its closure)